# Opinions on mapping fields of nested/hierarchical objects to flat list?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, office-interop

I'm writing a tool which accesses a word document to prefill it with data. The document has a subset of [custom document properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.customdocumentproperties?view=vsto-2017), each identified by a name, whose values are used to update fields in the document.

My ViewModel should both be able to initiate/update its instances from data of those document properties, aswell as write its values back and update the fields of the document.

Something like this:

```cs
class PersonVM : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
  // properties
  string Name { get; set; }
  string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

  // methods to get data or save data of this properties to or from the word document
  void saveMyPropertyValuesToWord()
  {
    // …
  } 

  void updateMyPropertiesFromWord()
  {
     // …
  }
}

class ProjectVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  int ProjectNumber { get; set; }
  PersonVM Manager { get; set; }
  PersonVM Mechanic1 { get; set; }
  PersonVM Mechanic2 { get; set; }

  void saveMyPropertyValuesToWord()
  {
     Manager.saveMyPropertyValuesToWord();
     Mechanic1.saveMyPropertyValuesToWord();
     Mechanic2.saveMyPropertyValuesToWord();

     // handle ProjectNumber  etc.
  } 

  void updateMyPropertiesFromWord()
  {
     Manager.updateMyPropertiesFromWord();
     Mechanic1.updateMyPropertiesFromWord();
     Mechanic2.updateMyPropertiesFromWord();

     // handle ProjectNumber  etc.
  }

  class CompanyVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    string Name { get; set; }
    PersonVM Owner { get; set; } 
    ProjectVM Project1 { get; set; }
    ProjectVM Project2 { get; set; }

    // …
  }

  // …
}
```

Right now I have a class with static string properties for each document property that might be present in a word document from which I would like to load the data accordingly:

```cs
class WordUtils 
{
  // Company
  static string CompanyName = "dp_CompanyName";
  // Company.Owner
  static string CompanyOwnerName = "dp_CompanyOwnerName";
  static string CompanyOwnerPhone = "dp_CompanyOwnerPhone";
  // Company.Project1
  static string CompanyProject1Number = "dp_CompanyProject1Number";
  // Company.Project1.Manager
  static string CompanyProject1ManagerName = "dp_CompanyProject1ManagerName";
  static string CompanyProject1ManagerPhone = "dp_CompanyProject1ManagerPhone";
  // Company.Project1.Mechanic1

  // … etc
}
```

Now back to implementing those `PersonVM.saveMyPropertyValuesToWord()` - I thought of something like this:

```cs
void saveMyPropertyValuesToWord()
{
   Name = MyApp.MyWordDocument.GetCustomProperty(WordUtils.OwnerName);
}
```

but here I need to know on class Level exactly what instance of it this is called from (i.e. what PersonVM am I, *Company.Owner* or *Project1.Manager* or ?) in order to decide which WordUtils.Name I need to provide.

I'm not sure how this should be done, maybe make PersonVM abstract and make a new class for each role (which would again only have one instance of itself, not very pretty in my eyes)?  I have also taken a short look at Attributes and expect those might be helpfull in this scenario. Maybe I am missing something obvious, but extensive search for a robust way to tackle this problem have been fruitless so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
class Property
{
    public string Key { get; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Property(string key) => Key = key;
}

interface IPropertyTree
{
    IEnumerable<IPropertyTree> ChildNodes { get; }
    IEnumerable<Property> Properties { get; }
}
class PersonVM : IPropertyTree
{
    private readonly string prefix;

    public PersonVM(string prefix)
    {
        Name = new Property(prefix + "Name" );
        PhoneNumber = new Property(prefix + "PhoneNumber");
    }

    public Property Name { get;  }
    public Property PhoneNumber { get;  }
    public IEnumerable<IPropertyTree> ChildNodes => Enumerable.Empty<IPropertyTree>();
    public IEnumerable<Property> Properties => new[] {Name, PhoneNumber};
}
static class PropertyTreeExtensions
{
    public static void Update(this IPropertyTree self)
    {
        foreach (var property in self.Flatten().SelectMany(tree => tree.Properties))
        {
            property.Value = MyApp.MyWordDocument.GetCustomProperty(property.Key);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IPropertyTree> Flatten(this IPropertyTree self)
    {
        var stack = new Stack<IPropertyTree>();
        stack.Push(self);
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var current = stack.Pop();
            yield return current;
            foreach (var child in current.ChildNodes)
            {
                stack.Push(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should allow each property to have a unique key, and keep the key and property value tightly coupled. It should also allow you to move the save/update logic to a centralized place.

Comment: After a look into c# extension methods that somehow eluded me until now, this does look like an awsome approach

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can implement a concrete class of `IPerson` for each type and hard code the individual implementations.

Since you know the person type the moment you are creating an instance of `PersonVMM`, you could add an attribute `PersonTypeId` and set it from the constructor,

```
void SomeMethod()
{
  var personVm = new PersonVM(WordUtils.OwnerName);
}

class PersonVM : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
  // properties
  string PersonTypeId { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
  string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

  public PersonVM() 
  {}

  public PersonVM(string personTypeId) 
  {
    PersonTypeId = personTypeId;
  }

  // methods to get data or save data of this properties to or from the word document
  void saveMyPropertyValuesToWord()
  {
    Name = MyApp.MyWordDocument.GetCustomProperty(PersonTypeId);
  }
}
```